# Nologin error in unix

Tags: shell, unix

Hi I am trying to run a shell script in putty(using which I get access to unix server)Once I run the script I am getting an error saying
 "no login:errfiles1.zip: cannot create" 
inside KSH I am creating a zip file which is then sent through mail using a mail utility.
But when I check the logs it's fine without any error. what is this no login error. Can anyone help me on this.

Below is the main program.

```
logmessage MSG "Started executing validate_feed.ksh job" >>$LOG_FILE
logmessage MSG "Calling feedvalidor.pl" >> $LOG_FILE
## Calling feed_validator.pl script to validate the generated feed files for all the regions
$(perl $ACE_CURRENT/feed_validator/bin_new/feed_validator.pl)
logmessage MSG "Completed executing perl script feed_validator.pl!!!!!!!" >> $LOG_FILE
logmessage MSG "finding .err files in $ErrFilePath ...." >> $LOG_FILE
FILES=$(find "$ErrFilePath" -type f  | sed 's/ /\\ /g' | grep ".err")
logmessage MSG "found .err files in $ErrFilePath " >> $LOG_FILE
logmessage MSG "FILES are $FILES " >> $LOG_FILE
if [ "$FILES" ]; then
alert=1
logmessage MSG "Enterrrrrrrrrred If - Mail" >> $LOG_FILE
logmessage MSG "Value of alert is $alert" >> $LOG_FILE
logmessage MSG "files are : $FILES ">>$LOG_FILE
zip -r "$FilePath/$ZipFolder" "$ErrFilePath"
logmessage MSG "CompressionNotRequired is  $CompressionNotRequired">>$LOG_FILE
##Calling exit_func which internally calls mail_func to send the mail with attached error files
exit_func
else
alert=0
exit_func
fi
logmessage MSG "Completed executing validate_feed.ksh job" >> $LOG_FILE
exit 0;
```

Comment: Could you post the shell script? Otherwise it is hard to help you...

Comment: The error tells you precisely what it says: you start some command which outputs the error that it failed to create that archive file. Since the command you start is not some locally installed command, but a script you hand over it does not have a name, therefore the name 'no login`is substituted to point our _what_ process or command raised the error.

Comment: But I ran the command separately in putty and it worked fine. Below is the command used.
zip -r "/usr/local/pbiace/current/feed_validator/errfiles1.zip" "/usr/local/pbiace/current/feed_validator/errfiles"

Answer (score 0):

I got the error. I was writing a print statement in my perl module. This was generating that no login error as I am running the shell script which internally calls the perl script.